# How can I make a website support Windows Live Writer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, windows-live-writer

I'm developing a custom website and I want it to support Windows Live Writer. Where can I find the specs so I can develop the server side code and handle Windows Live Writer requests?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "support Windows Live Writer"? Is this a blog site?

Comment: Not a blog so to speak but it needs to have the ability for creating content pages quickly. I've since decided to drop adding support for windows live writer as it only can cater for writing the content not the addition work (adding extra images and setting other settings).

Comment: You may want to try [Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573). It's free. It is aimed at SharePoint sites, but it has all you need to create content-based web sites. It used to be Microsoft FrontPage before it was "repurposed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this can help you:
http://www.cnblogs.com/Dah/archive/2007/04/02/697312.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live Writer uses XML-RPC to communicate with blog sites. See [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode55NotABlogALocalXMLRPCMetaWebLogEndpointThatLiesToWindowsLiveWriter.aspx) from Scott Hanselman for info on how to implement a website which can handle XML-RPC and Windows Live Writer. Mads Kristensen has also written a [mini blog engine](https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog) using the ideas in the Hanselman post and it supports Windows Live Writer.